# Core plot how to plot 2 y axis label, Graph looks blured

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I've Couple of issues:>>>> 
[image]

class ScatteredCell: UICollectionViewCell,CPTScatterPlotDataSource,CPTPlotDataSource,CPTScatterPlotDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet  var hostView: CPTGraphHostingView!

```
var plot1: CPTBarPlot!
var plot2: CPTBarPlot!
var plot3: CPTScatterPlot!
var indexOfCell:Int? = nil
var selectedComponent: String!
let BarWidth = 0.8
let BarInitialX = 1.0
let yArray = [0,0,3,0,2,1,0,1,5,0,0,5,8,0,0,1,0,0,6,0,7,0,3,5,5,0,2,0,0,1,0]
var valueBarPlot:Array<Any> = []
var fullBarPlot:Array<Any> = []
var yIntervalLength = NSNumber()

var yAxisScale = 0

override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
}
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 204.0/255.0, green: 204.0/255.0, blue: 204.0/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor
}
func initWithPlot()
{
    configureHostView()
    configureGraph()
    configureChart()
    configureAxes()
    configureLegend()
}

func configureHostView()
{
    hostView.allowPinchScaling = false
}

func configureGraph()
{

    // 1 - Create the graph
    let graph = CPTXYGraph(frame: hostView.bounds)
    graph.plotAreaFrame?.masksToBorder = false
    hostView.hostedGraph = graph
    // 2 - Configure the graph
    graph.fill = CPTFill(color: CPTColor.clear())
    graph.paddingBottom = 40.0
    graph.paddingLeft = 20.0
    graph.paddingTop = 20.0
    graph.paddingRight = 15.0



    let yLabelFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    yLabelFormatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = false

    // 4 - Set up plot space
    guard let plotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace as? CPTXYPlotSpace else { return }
    plotSpace.yRange = CPTPlotRange(location: 0, length:yAxisScale as NSNumber)
    var yAxisLength:NSNumber = 0
    if selectedComponent == "month"{
        yAxisLength = 31
    }else {
        yAxisLength = 12
    }

    plotSpace.xRange = CPTPlotRange(location:0.5, length:yAxisLength)
    let axisSet = (graph.axisSet as? CPTXYAxisSet)
    let axisSet1 = (graph.axisSet as? CPTXYAxisSet)
    let y: CPTXYAxis? = axisSet?.yAxis
    y?.labelFormatter = yLabelFormatter
    y?.axisConstraints = CPTConstraints.init(lowerOffset: -25.0)
    y?.plotSpace = plotSpace

    let x: CPTXYAxis? = axisSet?.xAxis
    x?.labelFormatter = yLabelFormatter
    graph.masksToBorder = true
        }

func configureChart()
{

    // 1 - take plot
    plot1 = CPTBarPlot()
    plot1.fill = CPTFill(color: CPTColor.init(componentRed: 25.0/255.0, green: 100.0/255.0, blue: 150.0/255.0, alpha: 1))

    plot2 = CPTBarPlot()
    plot2.fill = CPTFill(color: CPTColor.init(componentRed: 230.0/255.0, green: 230.0/255.0, blue: 230.0/255.0, alpha: 1))



    // 2 - Set up line style
    let barLineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    barLineStyle.lineColor = CPTColor.clear()
    barLineStyle.lineWidth = 1

    // 3 - configure plots to graph
    let barX = BarInitialX
    let plot:CPTBarPlot = plot1!
    plot.dataSource = self
    //plot.delegate = self
    plot.barWidth = NSNumber(value: BarWidth)
    plot.barOffset = NSNumber(value: barX)
    plot.lineStyle = barLineStyle
    //        barX += BarWidth
    let splot:CPTBarPlot = plot2!
    splot.dataSource = self

    //Add plots to graph
    guard let graph = hostView.hostedGraph else { return }
    graph.add(splot, to: graph.defaultPlotSpace)
    graph.add(plot, to: graph.defaultPlotSpace)
    let myBorderLineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    myBorderLineStyle.lineColor = CPTColor.clear()
    plot2.lineStyle = myBorderLineStyle
    plot2.barWidth = NSNumber(value: BarWidth)
    plot2.barOffset = NSNumber(value: barX)
    plot3 = CPTScatterPlot()
    let scatplot:CPTScatterPlot = plot3!
    scatplot.dataSource = self
    //Add plots to graph
    guard let graph1 = hostView.hostedGraph else { return }
    graph1.add(scatplot, to: graph.defaultPlotSpace)

    plot1.attributedTitle = attributedString("DISTANCE TRAVELLED(MILES)",fontSize: 7.0)
    plot3.title = "" //attributedString("TIME(HOURS)",fontSize: 8.0)
}
func configureAxes()
{
    // 1 - Configure styles
    let axisLineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    //let axisLineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = CPTColor.clear()

    // 2 - Get the graph's axis set
    guard let axisSet = hostView.hostedGraph?.axisSet as? CPTXYAxisSet else { return }

    let axisTextStyle = CPTMutableTextStyle()
    axisTextStyle.fontName = "Reg"

    let axisFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    axisFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1

    // 3 - Configure the x-axis
    if let x = axisSet.xAxis {
        var xAxisInterval:NSNumber = 0

        if selectedComponent == "month"{
            xAxisInterval = 5
        }else {
            xAxisInterval = 1
        }
        x.majorIntervalLength   = xAxisInterval
        x.orthogonalPosition    = 0
        x.minorTicksPerInterval = 2
        x.majorTickLength = 5
        x.attributedTitle = attributedString("MONTH",fontSize: 9.0)
        axisTextStyle.color = CPTColor.gray()
        axisTextStyle.fontSize = 6.0
        x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle


    }

    //if 4 - Configure the y-axis
    if let y = axisSet.yAxis{
        let identi = y.identifier
        print(identi)
        y.majorIntervalLength   = yIntervalLength
        y.majorTickLength = 5
        y.minorTicksPerInterval = 1
        y.orthogonalPosition    = 0
        y.axisConstraints =  CPTConstraints.init(lowerOffset: 5.0)
        axisTextStyle.color = CPTColor.init(componentRed: 25.0/255.0, green: 100.0/255.0, blue: 150.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
        axisTextStyle.fontSize = 6.0
        y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle
        y.labelFormatter = axisFormatter
    }
}
func configureLegend() {
    guard let graph = hostView.hostedGraph else { return }
    let legend = CPTLegend(graph: graph)
    graph.legend = legend
    graph.legendAnchor = .topLeft
    graph.legendDisplacement = CGPoint(x: 25.0, y: 0.0)
    legend.fill = CPTFill(color: CPTColor.white())
    legend.swatchSize = CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0)
    let titleStyle = CPTMutableTextStyle()
    titleStyle.color = CPTColor.black()
    titleStyle.fontSize = 11.0
    legend.textStyle = titleStyle
     legend.delegate = self
}
func attributedString(_ title:String, fontSize:CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let attributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: Font.Bold, size: fontSize) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0),
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(red: 127.0/255.0, green: 137.0/255.0, blue: 147.0/255.0, alpha: 1),
        ] as [String : Any]
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: attributes)
    return attributedString
}
// MARK: - Plot Data Source Methods
func numberOfRecords(for plot: CPTPlot) -> UInt
{

    return UInt(valueBarPlot.count)
}

func number(for plot: CPTPlot, field fieldEnum: UInt, record idx: UInt) -> Any?
{
    if fieldEnum == UInt(CPTBarPlotField.barTip.rawValue)
    {
        if plot == plot1
        {
            return self.valueBarPlot[Int(idx)] as! NSNumber;
        }
        if plot == plot2
        {
            return self.fullBarPlot[Int(idx)] as! NSNumber;
        }
        if plot == plot3
        {
            return self.yArray[Int(idx)] as NSNumber;
        }
    }
    return idx
}
```

}

issue 1: If i use upperoffset in Y axis, i'm not able to plot the 2nd y axis

Issue2: Pupulating the Host view in Collectionviewcell, it has 4 graph, so i used collectionview cell, i dont no why graph gets blured  in real device

Comment: #1: it's not clear what you're asking—please clarify. #2: How are you rendering the graph into the cell? Please provide a more detailed description and the relevant code.

Comment: Done @EricSkroch

Comment: Done @Eric Skroch

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking for part 1. From the way the red bar is overlaid over the other plot, it looks like it's part of another graph. For part 2, please post the code used to setup the collection view cell including the graph hosting view. What device is this screenshot from? Is it a simulator or real device?

Comment: Hi @EricSkroch , i've updated my code and issue stated clearly, could you please help me on it

Answer (score 0):

There is no mention of a second y-axis in the code provided. You need to create and configure a new axis object and add it to the axis set. See the "Axis Demo" in the *Plot Gallery* example app for sample code.

```
graph.axisSet.axes = [x, y, y2]
```

It's obvious that the graph hosting view isn't positioned correctly within the cell. I can't tell why from the information provided.

Comment: yes i tried this, it saves the same memory location for y axis

Comment: Make sure you're creating a new axis, not just reusing the old one. `y2 = CPTXYAxis()`

Comment: Thanks Eric Now both side Y axis comes. Now the interval of y axis is 0 -100 and for y2 0 -6 how to do in configureaxes  method, how to differentiate bot the y axis. @Eric Skroch

Comment: To use different scales for the axes, add another plot space to the graph and configure the `y2` axis to use it. You'll probably also want to add at least one of the plots to the new plot space, as well.